# Why is ""+ int flagged for Java in SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

In Java I can convert an int to a string by *"" + intValue*.
Sonarqube and sonarlint flag this as inappropriate.

Why is this  inappropriate. As far as I know *Integer.toString(intValue)* is more verbose and does the same.

I can imagine to flag it if not "" but Object x is used as in *x + intValue* where x is initialized as an integer. Ran into something like that with Javascript code.

Comment: because that is the most incorrect, naive way of converting an `int` ( or any other `Object` ) to a `String` representation that you can pick. This has been discourage for over a decade at this point.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson question is not a duplicate of the one you linked !

Comment: @Hans would you mind providing the rule key raising the issue?

Comment: @benzonico - damn copy paste in windows sucks!

Comment: [This is the duplicate that I was trying to copy paste as the close reason. The accepted answer answers this as well.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976731/convert-integer-double-to-string-in-java)

Comment: Sounds more like it :)

Comment: There are older duplicates, seems like ""+42 is optimized but ""+intValue not. Hoped that compiler had advanced more since I came back to the Duke force from .NET.

Comment: It's because the java compiler is lazy. If the value is a constant (iconst_x or ldc) then the compiler can merge and inline. However, because it's a variable, the compiler can't/won't bother checking whether it's possible to inline into one statement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With regards to why it's bad, Java automatically optimizes `String` concatenation to use `StringBuilder` instead. This means that by doing this

```
"" + d
```

You're actually doing

```
new StringBuilder().append(d).toString();
```

And if you do

```
d + ""
```

You end up compiling

```
new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(d)).toString();
```

Which is a pretty big waste of resources relative to just calling

```
String.valueOf(d);
```